# Using CSS to link to a page?

Tags: css, hyperlink

Would anyone happen to know how to use CSS to link to an internal page instead of using a href?

The situation is... I have a feed on a page from an external source  on another one of my website (which controls the link) I wish to use CSS at my end to change the direction of the link almost creating a feed without coding RSS.

As of now I am using the following code to kill the link as I would rather it go nowhere than to an undesired place:

```
.col-one-thirdtest a.item-link {
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Problem solved by using http://open.dapper.net/user-dapps.php and http://feed.informer.com/ in order to select the sections of the page I needed and then convert them into an RSS feed! Job Done!

Comment: Can you use Javascript?

Comment: CSS should be used only for displaying stuff. For such manipulations you should use JS or HTML.

Comment: I am quite terrible at JS, but I might give it a go just to get some JS skills. Was really looking for an easy fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. CSS is not a scripting/behvaioral language. It's a styling language. (Your `pointer-events` trick [doesn't work on all browsers, anyway](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events).)

You'll need to use JavaScript to change the link locations.

Also (as a side note), you might want to reconsider your reasons for having the feed from said external source if the links don't go where you want them to. The behavior you're asking for suggests that your feed might be the wrong way to go about your desired effect.